# Excel - SUMIF Adjacent Rows

Tags: excel

I have some data in one column.  I need to add up occurences of specific strings that occur in rows next to each other.

I am looking for the value "Available" in a row with the next row down containing "Inbound".

For example:

COLUMN C:

Inbound

Outbound

Available

Inbound

Available

Outbound

Available

Inbound

The above would result in the value "2" being returned as this happens twice.

How would I use Excel to do this?  I assume COUNTIF would be easiest/best but I am open to other suggestions.  The columns of data are several hundred rows and variable length.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Link to sample data file - http://soccer-supremo.com/Sample.xls

Comment: Could you add screenshot of how the data looks like, or provide a link to a dummy file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write an array formula. (Be sure to hold Ctrl+Shift pressed when hitting Return. Excel will insert curly brackets at beginning and end of line).

```
=SUM((C1:C10000="Available")*(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Inbound",C2:C10001))))*1)
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort but this doesn't work, it returns 0 regardless of the data.  It needs to return 1 for each occurence of the data in adjacent rows. ie if C6 is "Available" and C7 is "Inbound" then + 1 to the total.

Comment: Are you sure you created a array formula? Did the curly brackets appear? ... `{=SUM((C1:C10000="Available")*(C2:C10001="Inbound")*1)}`

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise - how do you do that?

Comment: After entering the formula in the cell or the formula bar you have to hold `Ctrl`+`Shift` keys pressed while pressing `Return` key to commit the formula... Just while the input focus is still on this formula.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that doesn't seem to do anything, I'm on Excel 2003 if that makes any difference.

Comment: So is the problem (A) there are no curly brackets if you inspect the formula in formula bar or (B) there are the brackets but the result in false in spite?

Comment: The formula appears to be working now but the result is 0 but it should be 7 using my test data.

Comment: Ok a last try before moving to chat. I checked for exact "Inbound" and not containing it. I updated my post. Hope I translated the excel functions correctly from my german version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62677/discussion-between-davidjwest-and-fratyx).

Answer (score 1):

Please try something of the kind:

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C9,"Available",C3:C10,"Inbound")
```

Comment: +1 - agree this is the way to go - given the data shown in sample file wildcards will be required with second criterion, i.e. `=COUNTIFS(C2:C100,"Available",C3:C101,"*Inbound*")`